# Creating a Pivot Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

I could use some help with creating a PIVOT table.

The table that I'm looking to pivot from is:

```
Track Number   Customer Number  Ship Date       Op Code     Curr      Surcharge Reason          Surcharge Amt
1100411007     326740721        2019-08-27      Ground      USD       Ground Fuel Surcharge     0.55
1100411007     126270721        2019-12-11      Ground      USD       Air Fuel Surcharge        0.45
1150481637     126170723        2019-01-19      Ground      USD       Residential Delivery      0.55
1150354456     125770746        2019-03-19      Ground      USD       Ext. Residential Del.     0.57
1150394131     126720765        2019-09-27      Ground      USD       Out of Area Delivery      0.50
1600746152     121770100        2019-03-12      Ground      USD       Ground Fuel Surcharge     0.52
```

Where I want to change it into the Format of

```
Track Number    Surcharge Reason #1         Surcharge Reason #2         Surcharge Reason #3        Surcharge reason #N 
Tracking #1     Surcharge Amt (if any)      Surcharge Amt (if any)      Surcharge Amt (if any)     ...
Tracking #2     Surcharge Amt (if any)      Surcharge Amt (if any)      Surcharge Amt (if any)     ...
Tracking #3     ...                         ...                         ...                        ...
Tracking #4     ...                         ...                         ...                        ...
Tracking #5     ...                         ...                         ...                        ...
...
```

Which has the tracking number as the Row Identifier, the added columns are the Unique Values in the 'Surcharge Reason' column, and the values of the data are the Surcharge Amount if there is any for that Track Number & Surcharge Reason

Any help on sending me down the right path would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Be great to see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your expected output using `case` statement. here is an example.

```
select
    trackNumber,
    sum(case when surchargeReason = 'Ground Fuel Surcharge' then amount else 0 end) as "Ground Fuel Surcharge"
from youTable
group by
    trackNumber
```

Comment: `case` is an **expression** not a *statement* :)

Comment: @DaleK When I use  `case expression` then I get a feedback that `case` is a `statement` not a expression. :) and then I looked at here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Comment: It depends on your RDBMS but as I am always telling OP's the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should be your first port of call :) and for SQL Server its an expression not a statement.

Comment: @zealous This is surprisingly way more simple than what I've been trying, and what I thought it would be. I just tried out your example of using a series of case statements, and it works EXACTLY how I wanted it to! Really appreciate help :)